# Format changed when save a pyspark dataframe into csv format which contains arraytype columns

Tags: python, pyspark

I have a spark dataframe which is attached below with 'region_validation_check_status','priority_validation_check_status' and so on. My concern is when I tried to save it in a csv file the data of these arrayType columns is split among number of columns which I really don't want.

Even I tried to cast these arraytype column to string before write it to csv but it doesn't work for me.

Please find the attached screenshot of output when saved it to csv file.
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is a common problem with csv. Save the files in parquet. Apart from being a binary format that allows encoded data types it is columnar and hence provides efficient data compression  with enhanced performance to handle complex data in bulk.

Comment: also see ORC format.

Comment: It means no chance to save it to .csv file ?

Comment: You can save as a CSV but you won't preserve dtypes. It also takes longer to read and write csv.